# Batch file stops if path not found

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that acceses multiple servers, finds certain folders and copies their content into my computer - into a newly created folder with the same name. This works BUT:

**THE PROBLEM** is that if the path is not found the batch stops and closes.

I tried to fix it with %ERRORLEVEL% but has no effect.
Please help.

My code:

```
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO END
pushd \\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N\
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "235110"') do (
cd ..
xcopy "%%a" "%destination%\CtrExtrase\235110NA\" /E /D /Y )
popd
@ECHO ---
:END
popd

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO END
pushd \\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N\
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "235449"') do (
cd ..
xcopy "%%a" "%destination%\CtrExtrase\235449NA\" /E /D /Y )
popd
@ECHO ---
:END
popd
```

Comment: You have more `popd` and `pushd`. Each popd is meant to match a pushd. Also, it seems that your ERRORLEVEL handling is *designed* to do exactly what you describe: stop when there's an error.

Comment: I used popd after :end so in case of any errors, the letter asiggned to the server by the first pushd will be deleted. With errorlevel is the first time I used it. I did something wrong. I'm learning vba and cmd for somehow 3 weeks :)

Comment: Why not use the `IF EXIST` command to see if the directory exists first.

Comment: Another problem.  You can't use the same label over and over again.  Labels are read from top down.

Comment: And one more problem: you are checking errorlevel after a loop. The errorlevel of a failed xcopy in the middle of the loop will be overwritten by the errorlevel from the next xcopy.

Comment: Ok. I will use different labes. But if as Squashman said i woud use "if path exists" and run the segment of the code ELSE go to the next segment to pathd and so on ?

Comment: There is a duplicate label `:END`, so execution might continue at the wrong place...

Comment: What does variable `%destination%` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is the logic you are trying to implement.  Should be easy enough to follow.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "\\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N\" (
    pushd "\\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N\"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "235110"') do (
        cd ..
        xcopy "%%a" "%destination%\CtrExtrase\235110NA\" /E /D /Y
    )
    popd
)


IF EXIST "\\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N\" (
    pushd "\\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N\"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "235449"') do (
        cd ..
        xcopy "%%a" "%destination%\CtrExtrase\235449NA\" /E /D /Y
    )
    popd
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to achieve the following:

```cmd
pushd "\\thunder\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 235001N - 237500N" && (
    for %%N in ("235110" "235449") do (
        for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /S /A:D "%%~N"') do (
            xcopy /I /E /D /Y "%%~A" "%destination%\CtrExtrase\%%~NNA\%%~nxA"
        )
    )
    popd
)
```